# Waiting for one of two elements to be displayed

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

So this app I'm automating at work has scenarios where the same button is used to navigate to different screens based on various scenarios that could happen. The app also has various timing issues that usually pop up during automation.

Previously I've used `WebDriverWait` for handling these timing issues by waiting for an element to be displayed / not displayed but now I find myself having to wait for element1 **or** element2 to be displayed.

I found a way of doing it with an `XPath` where I use the pipe character to essentially combine 2 xpaths:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(maxTimeoutInSeconds))            
.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//select[@id='dropdown']|//input[@id='firstname']")));
```

Is there a way to do this with something other than `XPath`, like `By.Id` or `By.LinkText`?

Is there a more recommended approach for handling a wait for element1 **or** element2?

**UPDATE**
I threw together a method based on a comment below and it's throwing a `NoSuchElementException` whenever the first `Displayed` condition is false and never actually making it to the 2nd.

```
public void WaitForStuff(By element1, By element2)
{
    try
    {
        new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)).Until(driver => driver.FindElement(element1).Displayed || driver.FindElement(element2).Displayed);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
         throw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I highly reccommend using this

```
wait.Until(driver => driver.FindElement(By.XPath("xpath")).Displayed
                  || driver.FindElement(By.XPath("xpath")).Displayed);
```

It stops at this line until one of the two elements is displayed. It's an ole' reliable for me. I use it countless times and it's rarely let me down.

## Edit

Seeing your update, here is an answer that takes into account the elements not existing.

```
Driver.Wait.Until(driver => (driver.FindElements(By.XPath("locationOne")).Any() && driver.FindElement(By.XPath("locationOne")).Displayed)
                         || (driver.FindElements(By.XPath("locationTwo")).Any() && driver.FindElement(By.XPath("locationTwo")).Displayed));
```

By looking for multiple elements, it won't throw element not found, but return an empty list, and if the list is empty it won't continue through the and statement, meaning it won't try to see if an element is displayed, unless it exists.

Comment: interesting. this looks like a much easier approach than everything else ive seen so far. ill definitely give this a shot later but it looks promising. thanks!

Comment: @user1818298 I know it's been a long time since you asked this question, but I don't get on stack overflow too often. I've updated my answer to include the problem you  found earlier